# Creating a High Score Screen in Java

Tags: java, treeset

I'm trying to create a highscore screen for a game that I'm working on. I wish to display the top ten scores of previous players as well as the scores of the players that just finished playing along with their ranking (order in the list of highscores). This list of highscores will be sorted according to their score and then their anme if the scores are the same. I have tried `ArrayLists` and `TreeSets` to do this. I am able to get both of these to sort the data accordingly but am having trouble pulling out the specific information for the players that just finished playing.

I have looked at maps but it seems like they won't work with the way I wish to sort the data. Can someone please direct me to a solution to this problem?

Here's a little scratch program I have made for one of them:

```
public class Tree_set_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String sName;
        int nAge, nNum, i=0;
        SortedSet<CFriend> tsFriends = new TreeSet<CFriend>();

        sName = "Jason";
        nAge = 5000;
        nNum = tsFriends.size() + 1;
        CFriend c1= new CFriend(sName,nAge,nNum);
        tsFriends.add(new CFriend(sName,nAge,nNum)); 

        sName = "Kenny";
        nAge = 200;
        nNum = tsFriends.size() + 1;
        CFriend c2= new CFriend(sName,nAge,nNum);
        tsFriends.add(new CFriend(sName,nAge,nNum)); 

        sName = "Smile";
        nAge = 100;
        nNum = tsFriends.size() + 1;
        tsFriends.add(new CFriend(sName,nAge,nNum)); 

        sName = "Hossein";
        nAge = 200;
        nNum = tsFriends.size() + 1;
        tsFriends.add(new CFriend(sName, nAge,nNum)); 

        sName = "People";
        nAge = 200;
        nNum = tsFriends.size() + 1;
        tsFriends.add(new CFriend(sName, nAge,nNum)); 

        Iterator itFriends = tsFriends.iterator(); // see note below on iterators.
        while (itFriends.hasNext()) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(itFriends.next());
        }
    }
}

class CFriend implements Comparable<CFriend> { 
    String sName;
    int nScore, nNum;

    CFriend(String _sName, int _nAge, int _nNum) {// constructor to load vars
        sName = _sName;
        nScore = _nAge;
        nNum=_nNum;
    }

    public int compareTo(CFriend other) {
        if (nScore > other.nScore) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (nScore < other.nScore) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            if (sName.compareTo(other.sName) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (sName.compareTo(other.sName) > 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return sName + " " + String.valueOf(nScore);
    }
}
```

I want to check where `c1` and `c2` are in the `TreeSet` and display that along with their `name` and `age`.

Comment: Just as a very small hint: If you go with an ArrayList, you can use the [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method to get the index of a specific object in the collection. You'll need to make sure your class implements the `equals` method though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Player class with a name and score. Then have it implement the `Comparable` interface. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

You can save the Player objects in an ArrayList and sort them using `Collections.Sort(yourArrayList);`

Your Player class could look something like this:

```
public class Player implements Comparable<Player>{

int score;
String name;

@Override
public int compareTo(Player o) {

//compare here

}


}
```

Comment: If this is for a social gaming application (or a game with a large number of players) - sorting the list every time a player completes a game is not scalable.

Comment: You should use a database for it then I think.

Comment: Database would be an even worse solution!!

Comment: Maybe use a highscore table. Only sort if the score is higher then someone in the that table.

Comment: if I do that then how can I tell a person where they are in the ranking? Don't think that will work.

Comment: You want to rank everything? Or something like a top 20?

Comment: I want to display the top ten on the screen and then the position of the two players that just played. So for the two players that just played it will show something like:                           (rank)215   (name)Joe  (score)5123

Comment: You need to insert your score in the right row index. So the table is always sorted. Try something like that I guess. Or look for big table sorting.

Comment: just a heads up for anyone reading this solution, the link is broken